# how to read data from a text file and iterate in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a text file in below format. I am looking to read all the data from the file and pass one value as an argument to the next command.

**dummy.txt**

```
Administrators
Guests
```

Basically these are the names of user groups and I am using .NET command to remove a user from a specific group.

How can I loop through the file (dummy.txt) and execute the below command to remove specific groups for a user?

```
NET LOCALGROUP GROUP_NAME Administrator /delete
```

I have tried something like this till now but no luck.

```
@echo off
for /f %%X in ("C:\dummy.txt") do (NET LOCALGROUP %%X Administrator /delete)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
    for /f "usebackq" %%X in ("c:\my file path\dummy.txt") do (
        NET LOCALGROUP %%X Administrator /delete
    )
```

The `usebackq` is used to allow the usage of single quotes inside the executed command and to indicate to the `for` parser that the double quoted string is a file reference and not an immediate string to parse.

Comment: Thanks timrau and MC ND.  That really helped a lot.

Comment: assume dummy.txt contains below values then how can we pass it to correctly to the NET command in the loop. `code` Administrator BACKUP Operators `code`. BACKUP OPERATORS is a single string but due to space character it is causing problem.

Comment: @monoj, you must indicate to the `for /f` command that spaces are not delimiters: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%X in ...` By default spaces and tabs delimit tokens. A empty list of delimiters disables this behaviour.

Comment: @monoj, and remember to quote the parameter `NET LOCALGROUP "%%X" ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the double quotes containing filename.

```
for /f %%X in (C:\dummy.txt) do (NET LOCALGROUP %%X Administrator /delete)
```

Comment: actually my file path contains space in between and thats why I have used double quote and If I remove double quote then path can not be found error occurs. how can we use c:\my file path\dummy.txt in the command.